# No Matching Records found in the First Page and Previous data still displayed on the Next Page

Tags: php, ajax, postgresql, datatables

i have a problem when using datatables to show data from postgresql, here are my problem.

i have 666 entries on my tables, but in the first page the datatables show a message No matching records found, even though the datatables displayed that it's Showing 1 to 10 of 666 entries,

And when i try to go to the next page (2nd page), the message was gone and the data from 11 to 20 records displayed.

And then when i try to go to the third page, the datatables still displayed the previous data (from the 2nd page) but the data from 21 to 30 records diplayed too, even though the datatables displayed that it's Showing 21 to 30 of 666 entries.

it was occuring when i go to the next page, the previous data still displayed in datatables.

Would you mind to tell me a solution for my problem? because i have been stuck on it for almost 1 weeks.
Thanks.

here's my server side processing code,

`

```
// initilize all variable
$params = $columns = $totalRecords = $data = array();


$params = $_REQUEST;


//define index of column
$columns = array( 
    0 =>'terminal_id',
    1 =>'tid', 
    2 => 'merchant_id',
    3 => 'encrypted_ktm'
);


$where = $sqlTot = $sqlRec = "";


// check search value exist
if( !empty($params['search']['value']) ) {   
    $where .=" WHERE ";
    $where .=" ( tid::text LIKE '%".$params['search']['value']."%' ";    
    $where .=" OR merchant_id::text LIKE '%".$params['search']['value']."%' ";
    $where .=" OR encrypted_ktm LIKE '%".$params['search']['value']."%' )";
}


// getting total number records without any search
$sql = "SELECT terminal_id, tid, merchant_id, encrypted_ktm FROM terminal";
$sqlTot .= $sql;
$sqlRec .= $sql;

//concatenate search sql if value exist
if(isset($where) && $where != '') {

    $sqlTot .= $where;
    $sqlRec .= $where;
}


$sqlRec .=  " ORDER BY ". $columns[$params['order'][0]['column']]."  ".$params['order'][0]['dir']." LIMIT ".$params['start']." OFFSET ".$params['length']." ";



$queryTot = pg_query($sqlTot);


$totalRecords = pg_num_rows($queryTot);


$queryRecords = pg_query($sqlRec);


//iterate on results row and create new index array of data
while( $row = pg_fetch_row($queryRecords) ) { 
    $data[] = $row;
}   


$json_data = array(
        "draw"            => intval( $params['draw'] ),   
        "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalRecords ),  
        "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalRecords),
        "data"            => $data   // total data array
        );


echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format
```

**And here's my Javascript Code**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#employee_grid').DataTable({
                              "processing": true,
                      "serverSide": true,
                      /*"ajax": "response.php".*/
                      "ajax":{
                        url :"response.php", // json datasource
                        type: "post",  // type of method  , by default would be get
                        error: function(){  // error handling code
                          $("#employee_grid_processing").css("display","none");
                        }
                      }
              });   
});
```

Comment: You don't show your HTML, but it looks like you're applying that `display:none` to your first page as a result of some sort of non-fatal error.  You might add some code to display error messages in your error function.

Comment: sorry for slow response, i have already got the solution about this problem. the problem was query of limit [start] and offset [length] in response.php file.

it should be limit [length] offset [start].